# Not Displaying Search results on another component in angular 4

Tags: angular

Created a search bar in layout component.I want to show search results in another HTML component.I am getting empty results while Searching a record and i have created Search method in a service.

**service:**

```
getSearchList(event) {
    const headerOptions = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  this.authenticationService.token});
    const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: headerOptions });
    this.http.get('/api/search/' + event.target.value , requestOptions)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('data from server', response.json());
        return response.json() as Patient[];})
      .toPromise().then(x => {
        this.patientList1 = x;
        console.log('data from server', this.patientList1);
      });
  return this.patientList1;
}
```

**layoutcomponent typescript file**

```
search(event: any) {
    setTimeout(() => this.ref.markForCheck());

    this.patientService.getSearchList(event);
    console.log('#####patients inside ngonit===', this.patientList1);
    this.router.navigate(['/search']);
}
```

**searchcomponent.html**

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Phone</th>

    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let pat of patientService.patientList1">
        <td>{{ pat.ID }} -</td>
        <td>{{ pat.firstname }} - </td>
        <td>{{ pat.lastname }} - </td>
        <td>{{ pat.phone }} - </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The below image shows like that
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gBfM.png)
Please solve my issue.

Comment: where do you call search ? in NgOnInit method ?

Comment: In home component it is for global 
based on event.target.value  calling service of shared folder